# What is non-hückel double bond of Aromaticity?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

Chemistry of Aromaticity. What's non hückel double bond ? 
What are the difference between hückel and non-hückel double bond ?[image] 
[ Here, in figure the green one is non hückel double bond ]

Comment: There is no intrinsic difference. Hückel's rule counts the number of pi electrons *in a closed ring*. It says nothing about *other* double bonds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given molecule Pyrene , the π  bond shown in green is in [cross conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-conjugation) (shown in green in figure 1). This bond( figure 2) is excluded from interaction with rest of conjugated system. Hence , the central $\ce{C=C}$ isn't hosted by the largest p orbital loop, so it's not counted towards Hückel's rule for aromaticity.

The outer periphery (shown in blue in figure 3), is a loop of $\ce{14 π}$ electrons , therefore aromatic. This may be possible hückel double bond you are referring to.

The π bond in cross-conjugation (shown in green) maybe non-hückel double bond.

[image: Pyrene structure]

Comment: Beware: The central pi bond does not count towards the Hückel rule, however that does NOT mean that bond is not part of the aromatic system!